# Saving values to another document in Lua with Corona SDK

Tags: lua, global-variables, coronasdk, lua-table

I'm trying to save highscores to a table whenever a `gameOver` function is called.

When I go back in the app and try to read the highscores(They're displayed as newText where text is set to the proper highscore of the level.).

But it's not doing what it's supposed to. I can read the the levels highscores but when I try to change the values in the table, the highscore text doesn't change.

I have my main.lua and a myData.lua - The highscore table should be placed in the myData.lua in order to reach it from all the levels in the game. 
this is my table

```
highScores = {  
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7
}
```

and I was trying to save/change the value with

```
highScores[1] = score
```

Where `score` is the score count in-game.

I've realized this is not the way to go about it, and what I can find on google seems to overly complicated for what I see as a simple task.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my entire level1.lua - The actual level that's running and trying to save it's score to the highScore table level1.lua):

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
local myData = require( "myData" )
local physics = require("physics")
physics.setDrawMode( "hybrid" )
-- forward references
local w = display.actualContentWidth
local h = display.actualContentHeight
local dropCount = 0
local spawnShit = 0
local allowDrop = 1
local spawnTime = 17
local countdownTimer
local score
local gX = 0
local gY = 0
score = 0
local countDownNumber = 10
local gameOver

local scoreT = display.newText( {text="Score: "..score, font=system.nativeSystemFont, fontSize=14,} )
scoreT.x = w * 0.5
scoreT.y = h * 0.1

local countDownText = display.newText( {text="", font=system.nativeSystemFont, fontSize=14} )
countDownText.x = w * 0.5
countDownText.y = h * 0.2

local drop01 = display.newImage("drop01.png")
drop01.x = -100

local drop02 = display.newImage("drop02.png")
drop02.x = -100

local drop03 = display.newImage("drop03.png")
drop03.x = -100

local drop04 = display.newImage("drop04.png")
drop04.x = -100

local timerSpawn
local timer2

-- Display objects
local background = display.newImage( "bluebg.png" )
background.x = w*0.5
background.y = h*0.5
background.width = w 
background.height = h 

local bckBtn = display.newText({text="<--BACK", font=system.nativeSystemFont, fontSize=14})
bckBtn.x = 50
bckBtn.y = 20


local egon = display.newImage( "Egon.png" )
egon.x = w*0.5
egon.y = h*0.85
egon.width = 100
egon.height = 97

local destroyAll = display.newRect( 0, h, w, 10 )
destroyAll.width = w*2
destroyAll.alpha = 0

local overlayBg = display.newRect( -500, -500, w, h )
overlayBg:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )
overlayBg.alpha = 0.4

--functions

function gameOver ()
    if timerSpawn == nil then
    else
        timer.cancel(timerSpawn)
        timerSpawn = nil
        spawnShit = 0
    end
    if countdownTimer == nil then
    else
        timer.cancel(countdownTimer)
        countdownTimer = nil
    end
    highScores[1] = score
    transition.to( overlayBg, {x=w/2, y=h/2, time=500 } )
end

function goBack (event)
    if "began" == event.phase then
        gameOver()
        if timerSpawn == nil then
        else
            timer.cancel(timerSpawn)
        end
        if countdownTimer == nil then
        else
            timer.cancel(countdownTimer)
        end

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then 

        timer2 = timer.performWithDelay(1000, function()
            composer.gotoScene("select", "fade", 500)
        end)

        if overlayBg == nil then
        else
            overlayBg:removeSelf( )
        end

        return true
    end

    return true 
end

function moveEgon (event)
    if "moved" == event.phase then
        egon.x = event.x
    end

end 

------------------------------------------------vvv---------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------vvv---------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------vvv---------------------------------------------------
function spawnObjects (event)

    dropCount = math.random(1,4)

    --if stopTimer == 1 then
      --  timerSpawn = nil
        --spawnShit = nil
    --end
    if spawnShit == 1 then
        print( 'spawnShit' )
        if dropCount == 1 then
            -- Drop01 function and settings
            drop01 = display.newImage( "drop01.png" )
            drop01.x = math.random(10, 470)
            drop01.y = -40
            drop01.width = 50
            drop01.height = 50
            drop01.myName = "01"
            physics.addBody( drop01, "dynamic", {density=0.9, friction=0.1, bounce=0.8 } )

        elseif dropCount == 2 then 
            --Do shit for drop02
            drop02 = display.newImage( "drop02.png" )
            drop02.x = math.random(10, 470)
            drop02.y = -40
            drop02.width = 50
            drop02.height = 50
            drop02.myName = "02"
            physics.addBody( drop02, "dynamic", {density=0.9, friction=0.1, bounce=0.8 } )

        elseif dropCount == 3 then
            drop03 = display.newImage( "drop03.png" )
            drop03.x = math.random(10, 470)
            drop03.y = -40
            drop03.width = 50
            drop03.height = 50
            drop03.myName = "03"
            physics.addBody( drop03, "dynamic", {density=0.9, friction=0.1, bounce=0.8 } )

        elseif dropCount == 4 then
            drop04 = display.newImage( "drop04.png" )
            drop04.x = math.random(10, 470)
            drop04.y = -40
            drop04.width = 50
            drop04.height = 50
            drop04.myName = "04"
            physics.addBody( drop04, "dynamic", {density=0.9, friction=0.1, bounce=0.8 } )
        end
    end

    return true
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function onCollision (event)

    if "began" == event.phase then
    --v--do shit when touching surface

        if event.other.myName == "01" then
            -- Do shit for drop01 -- 
            -- Change score, powersups etc
            event.other:removeSelf( )
            score = score+1
            countDownNumber = countDownNumber + 10
            scoreT.text = "Score: "..score
        end

        if event.other.myName == "02" then
            -- Do shit for drop02 -- 
            -- Change score, powersups etc
            event.other:removeSelf( )
            score = score+1
            scoreT.text = "Score: "..score
        end

        if event.other.myName == "03" then 
            -- Do shit for drop03 -- 
            -- Change score, powersups etc
            event.other:removeSelf( )
            score = score-1
            scoreT.text = "Score: "..score
        end

        if event.other.myName == "04" then
            -- Do shit for drop04 -- 
            -- Change score, powersups etc
            event.other:removeSelf( )
            score = score-1
            scoreT.text = "Score: "..score
        end

    elseif "ended" == event.phase then 
    -- Do shit when leaving surfaces
    end     

    return true

end

------------------------------------------------vvv---------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------vvv---------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------vvv---------------------------------------------------
function showCountDown (event)
    -- Condition to show and hide countdown
    if countDownNumber <= 1 or score == -1 then
        spawnShit = 0
        countDownNumber = 0
        timer.cancel(timerSpawn)
        timer.cancel(countdownTimer)
        countdownTimer = nil
        highScores[1] = score
        print( 'NO MORE SPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWWNS' )
    end

    if countDownNumber >= 1 then
        countDownNumber = countDownNumber -1 
        countDownText.text = countDownNumber
        spawnShit = 1
    end

    return true
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


function destroy (event)

    if "began" == event.phase then
        event.other:removeSelf( )
        else if "ended" == event.phase then 
        end
        return true
    end
end


--function scene:create( event )
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Initialize the scene here.
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc

    --Listeners

    background:addEventListener( "touch", moveEgon )
    bckBtn:addEventListener( "touch", goBack )
    egon:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
    destroyAll:addEventListener( "collision", destroy )

    --SceneGroup insert
    sceneGroup:insert( background )
    sceneGroup:insert(egon)
    sceneGroup:insert(bckBtn)
    sceneGroup:insert(drop01)
    sceneGroup:insert(drop02)
    sceneGroup:insert(drop03)
    sceneGroup:insert(drop04)
    sceneGroup:insert(scoreT)
    sceneGroup:insert(countDownText)
    sceneGroup:insert(overlayBg)
    sceneGroup:insert(destroyAll)

end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
        -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
        physics.start( )
        gX = 0
        gY = 10
        physics.setGravity( gX, gY )
        timercount = 10
        spawnShit = 1
        score = 0
        scoreT.text = "Score: "..score

        -- ADD physic bodies ----
        physics.addBody( egon, "static", {density=0.1, friction=0.1, bounce=0.8 } )
        physics.addBody( destroyAll, "static", {density=0.1, friction=0.1, bounce=0.1 } )
        countDownNumber = 10
        if countdownTimer == nil then
            countdownTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, showCountDown, 0 )
        else
        end

        ----------- Timers ------------
        if timerSpawn == nil then
            timerSpawn = timer.performWithDelay(500, spawnObjects, 0 )
        else 
        end

    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, 
        --timer.pause( timerSpawn )
        physics.stop()
        spawnShit = nil
        score = nil
        timerSpawn = nil
        countdownTimer = nil
        overlayBg = nil

        --timer.cancel(timerSpawn)

        physics.removeBody( egon )

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.
    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
    bckBtn:removeEventListener("touch", goBack )
    egon:removeEventListener("touch", moveEgon )
end



-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: I undestand `highScore` is in the scope of the gameOver function, since you don't get any nil value indexing errors. But are you certain that it is **the** table you want to change that is in scope? Perhaps there's another `highScore` local table that you're changing? You might want to give more specifics, your entire code perhaps?

Comment: I can try and post the code in question, sure. 
I'm not getting any errors, it just seems like the highScore table is reset to it's original values.

Comment: @W.B. I've added a download link to my level1.lua file. It contains all of the code that I'm using for this purpose.

Comment: Well, let's start over. How do you know your score is not assigned to the table? How are you checking it? And what do you really want to do - assign the score to the table's first element (which is what you're doing now) or put it at the end of the highScore table?

Comment: I'm using a level select screen, with 7 levels with their text display set to highScore[1], highScore[2] and so on. So when I'm at the level select screen i can see level1, level2 and so forth. When I complete level 1, it's supposed to change the text from 1 to whatever the highScore[1] is. 
And yes, I'm trying to assign it to the first element, being level 1's highScore, level to would then call highScore[2]. 
I'm new at Lua so I'm not sure if there's an easier way of doing this, but I like to just do trial and error.

Comment: @W.B. Btw, I have also tried declaring each level with
 highScore1 = 1 
highScore2 = 2 and so forth

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. Where and how are you checking that the score has been changed? I haven't seen your other level files, so it's a complete guess, but is it possible that each of the level files contains `require(myData)` statement? If so, that would mean that each level is loading the table `highScore = {"1", "2", ...}` into global namespace. Also, which framework are you using?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm not checking for the score to be changed, I can only verify if the text that displays it is changed. 
And yes you are correct, both files require(myData) should they not? Is it possible to call values from another document without? And I'm using Corona SDK.

Comment: I've changed the title and tags to CoronaSDK my bad for not mentioning.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. You're overwriting the global `highScores` each time a level is loaded. You should probably require myData in the `main.lua`, when you initialise your app.

Comment: Please post the code in your question: I do not have access to that site due to security restrictions on my system. For formatting: put code in notepad++ or other text editor, replace all tabs with four spaces, select all, indent 4 spaces, copy paste into post.

Comment: @W.B. If i only require(myData) in main.lua i get an error nill value when i open levelselect.

Comment: @Schollii I can't post my code in here, for some reason( i think it's because i use many spaces) the code wont format properly. So it's pretty much un-readable. I would love to post it to another downloade site or whatever if you have one you prefer :)

Comment: @MNDevelopments never heard of that happening re format. Did you replace tabs with 4 spaces?

Comment: Just tried again. Half of my code is showing outside the code boxes. This is my comments, start of functions and some of my forward references is also for some reason not working.

Comment: @MNDevelopments Just make sure there are least 4 spaces before each line. If the code looks fine in your editor and you are not using tabs, then it should just work. Feel free to post it all messed up and I'll fix it.

Comment: @ScholliiI will make a "speciel edit for Schollii" with whatever messed up syntax it gives me. The code is readable for most of it, just a lot of junk that has no formatting. Editing post now.

Comment: Ok by adding four spaces to every line manually i got it to to format! peew.

Comment: @MNDevelopments I don't know why it doesn't work. It should. An alternative solution would be to create a table and attach it to storyboard. That way you can access it from everywhere. `storyboard.highScores = {"1", "2", ...}`. Then in your levels you can access it the same way - through `storyboard.highScores`. Or better `storyboard.globalState = {}` and then `storyboard.globalState.highScores = {"1", "2", ...}`.

Comment: @W.B. Allright can i still use storyboard when I'm using composer to handle scenes? But i will definitely look in to that option. 
Also could i'd be a simulator issue? I think i might port it to my phone tomorrow and see if fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright. The scores are being saved. The problem was the way i displayed the score text, because it wasn't reloading, it was just re-using the old value.

FIX: 
i added an

```
score01.text = highScore[1]
```

everytime the scene shows and it automatically updates the score when the select screen shows.